# Updated to Big Sur and find -exec results in permission denied

Tags: terminal, permission, big-sur

I have recently updated to Big Sur from Mojave (not willingly). I have tried to copy a bunch of pdfs in Terminal using the command:

```
find . -name "*_20*.pdf" -exec {} ~/Desktop/. \;
```

but it results in "permission denied". This command used to work before and indeed I can execute

```
cp my_fav_file_2010.pdf ~/Desktop
```

without a problem.

Terminal and iTerm are added to have "Full Disk Access" in the Privacy and Security Preferences. I even reached into /usr/bin and added `find` and `zsh` from /bin/ to the list, but it still gives me "permission denied". Any tips what is going on and how to fix this?

kJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `find` invocation:

> `find . -name "*_20*.pdf" -exec {} ~/Desktop/. \;`

If your PDF was named “Foo_20.pdf” then when `find` matched it it would attempt to run `Foo_20.pdf ~/Desktop/.` which is an attempt to execute the PDF as if it were an executable, and of course because it’s not (specifically, because it lacks the `+x` file permission) you get a `permission denied` error.

Your command is missing a `cp` invocation:

```
find . -name "*_20*.pdf" -exec cp {} ~/Desktop/. \;
```

Comment: Massive facepalm emoji :-) Thank you!